# Android Signing Key corrupt

Tags: android, key, apk

I created an app a few days ago that is on the Play Store.
Today I was going to update my app with some changes when I ran into a few problems.

Android Studio complaint about my .jks key and said that it was corrupt (This is the key I've used to upload the app in the beginning)

And now when trying to generate a signed apk I also get the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'. 
> Failed to read key from keystore
```

I tried by creating a new key and generate a signed apk which worked fine. However when I try to upload it to Google Play I get an error saying that I can't upload an update of the app with a different key or something among those lines.

So my question is, is it possible in some way to still upload an update of the app with a new key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had a similar problem a while back and my issue was the fact that I was typing an incorrect Key Alias. In my case I was typing Web View App when it should've been WebViewApp.

So what I would do first is to make sure that the key alias is correct, and also make sure that the password is correct.